# Security exception SmtpClient

Tags: 2013, email

I'm trying to send an email with an `SmtpClient`, but I get a security error when it tries to create the client. The troubleshooting tips mention security requirements when deploying an office solution, but I'm having trouble finding any information about how to configure that. Is there a special permission in Sharepoint somewhere to allow web parts to use SmtpClients? If so, I couldn't find it.

It seems there are multiple possible causes for this error, do you have any insight as to what is most likely to cause this issue?

[image: Error when creating client]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enclosing your code in [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx), this will run the code under App Pool account and thus have the permissions..